# Thoughtworks go: pass environment variable to a task

Tags: thoughtworks-go

How can I pass the GO environment variable to a task.  ie

```
grunt build-discovery-dev --buildNumber=" ${GO_PIPELINE_COUNTER}.
```

I want the GO_Pipeline_counter to be replaced with the actual value ie 56.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on where you invoke the command from

Shell

```
grunt build-discovery-dev --buildNumber=$GO_PIPELINE_COUNTER
```

Powershell

```
grunt build-discovery-dev --buildNumber=$env:GO_PIPELINE_COUNTER
```

Cmd

```
grunt build-discovery-dev --buildNumber=%GO_PIPELINE_COUNTER%
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap environment variables with '%'. E.g.:

```
grunt build-discovery-dev --buildNumber=" %GO_PIPELINE_COUNTER%.
```

Answer (score 0):

The braces characters (as in `${VAR}`) do not work in GoCD tasks. You really must only use the dollar sign without braces (as in `$VAR`) for correct replacement of a variable with its value.